# how can i fix this "ajax request entity too large"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js

I'm using Chart.JS. I want to encode canvas as base64 and deliver it to the server. But the capacity is too big, so I keep getting errors. Do you happen to know how to solve it?

Here's my code. Help!

I would like to send an array containing table data and two canvas encoded in base64.

```
function excelExport() {
            var myTableArray = [];
            $("table#tableData tr").each(function () {
                var arrayOfThisRow = [];
                var tableData = $(this).find('td');
                if (tableData.length > 0) {
                    tableData.each(function () { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
                    myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
                }
            });
            $("table#tableData1 tr").each(function () {
                var arrayOfThisRow = [];
                var tableData = $(this).find('td');
                if (tableData.length > 0) {
                    tableData.each(function () { arrayOfThisRow.push("Unit1" + $(this).text()); });
                    myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
                }
            });
            $("table#tableData2 tr").each(function () {
                var arrayOfThisRow = [];
                var tableData = $(this).find('td');
                if (tableData.length > 0) {
                    tableData.each(function () { arrayOfThisRow.push("Unit2" + $(this).text()); });
                    myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
                }
            });
            $("table#Unit1Table tr").each(function () {
                var arrayOfThisRow = [];
                var tableData = $(this).find('td');
                if (tableData.length > 0) {
                    tableData.each(function () { arrayOfThisRow.push("Unit1Y" + $(this).text()); });
                    myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
                }
            });
            $("table#Unit2Table tr").each(function () {
                var arrayOfThisRow = [];
                var tableData = $(this).find('td');
                if (tableData.length > 0) {
                    tableData.each(function () { arrayOfThisRow.push("Unit2Y" + $(this).text()); });
                    myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
                }
            });

            var dataURL1 = canvas1.toDataURL(1.0);
            var dataURL2 = canvas2.toDataURL(1.0);
            var image__1 = dataURL1;
            var image__2 = dataURL2;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                //data: JSON.stringify(myTableArray,image__1,image__2),
                data: {TableData : myTableArray, FirstChart : image__1, SecondChart : image__2},
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: '/PostExcelExport',
                success: function (data1) {
                    console.dir(data1);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert("실패 : " + err);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: This is a limitation of your server. You may be able to configure it to accept larger requests, but we won't be able to help you if you don't describe your server in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I fixed the limit of the server side Parser part to 50mb and solved it.